# Get the ID from the row what have a big value gap with the previous one - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the row whats have the value much bigger than its previous, like that:

```
name    value
angelo  1
petter  1
marco   2
thiago  10
jose    9
```

I would like to get Thiago row, for example.

I cant figure out how I can do it with a good performance.

Comment: Tables in SQL represent unordered sets.  There is no "previous row" unless you define a column that has the ordering.

Comment: There is id column there, i just don,t paste the full table, i thought that was enough to understand my question.

Comment: Don't you mean that you want `jose`? The ordering of the records in the database is meaningless and coincidental, typically based more on the primary key than insert order... at least eventually. If you think the record order matters, you need a column that allows you enforce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a column that indicates an order. I assume you have an `id` column for that

```
select name from
(
  select name, 
         case when abs(@v-value) > 2 then 1 else 0 end as big_diff, 
         @v := value
  from your_table
  cross join (select @v := 0) tmp_v
  order by id
) x 
where big_diff = 1
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ac3a/6)

Comment: There is an id in my table, u just dont copy that, because i thought that example i post would be enough , thank you, i will test that code.